# Get token auth value to another dart using sharedprefence

Tags: flutter, dart

how to retrieve token variable from sharedprefence in flutter?
i am very new to implement api for my flutter project because previously I was only told to work on the frontend, i have saved auth token in login and here is my code to store token in sharedprefence

```
signIn(String email, password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("/api/login"), body: data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsonResponse != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['data']['token']['original']['token']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
    else {
      
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("Mohon cek Email dan Password kembali!", textAlign: TextAlign.center,), backgroundColor: Colors.red,));
    }
  }
```

and here is the darts place that I want to call the token for auth in the post method

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:kiriapp/models/angkot.dart';
class AngkotProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  
  late AngkotModel _angkot;
  AngkotModel get angkot => _angkot;
  set angkot(AngkotModel newAngkot) {
    _angkot = newAngkot;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  static Future<AngkotModel?> tambah(
      String user_id,
      String route_id,
      String plat_nomor,
      String pajak_tahunan,
      String pajak_stnk,
      String kir_bulanan) async {
    try {
      var body = {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'route_id': route_id,
        'plat_nomor': plat_nomor,
        'pajak_tahunan': pajak_tahunan,
        'pajak_stnk': pajak_stnk,
        'kir_bulanan': kir_bulanan,
      };
      print(body);
      
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('api/create'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $howtocallthetoken?,
        },
        body: body,
      );
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        return AngkotModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else if (response.statusCode == 400) {
        return AngkotModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      }{
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store something in shared preference we use `setString` function, just like you did. Now to retrieve it, you should use `getString` and it will return the token you stored earlier.

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String accessToken = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
  
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('api/create'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    },
    body: body,
  );
```

Don't forget to make the function async, and handle null values as the `getString` function might return token as `null` if not stored correctly.